# Como alterar fonte em um projeto Angular?

Tags: angular

Estou tentando alterar fonte em um projeto Angular e estou tentando adicionar em "styles" no angular.json e não tem efeito algum.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão ou pode me indicar um processo?

OBS: Sou iniciante com angular.

Answer (score 1):

no seu arquivo style.scss

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");

* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Lembrando que isso é um css então segue a precedencia normal de css

Answer (score -3):

Outra opção no Angular, vai no seu arquivo index.html na raiz do projeto e inclui uma tag do Google Font (gerar tag lá no Google font).

```html
 <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@300;400;600;900&amp;family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&amp;family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&amp"
  >
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).